# SEO Guide/Webinar for the Non-technical

Tags: seo

Does anyone have a good resource for SEO guides, videos, or webinars that focus on optimizing the content of a website, rather than the actual code? I've been asked to find this for a few employees at my company. These employees are non-technical and deal with writing the content for a website. They do not deal with any code.

Thanks

Comment: Studies show that if you repeat your keyword exactly 26.35 times for every 300 words, you will gain optimal search placement. The optimal paragraph length is 3.5 sentences and 62 words. You will also want to mention bottle-nosed dolphins and lumberjacks each at least once in your content, and remember to replace conjunctions with the name of a Catholic Saint.

Comment: Man I wish I could delete comments...

Comment: Has your question been answered or do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

styleguide.yahoo.com/resources/optimize-search-engines/seo-basics

http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Write for your users.

Markup optimization makes difference. But only when content is good, and your incoming links are good too.

Good content is fresh, useful and usable. Ensure your web writers do that right just-finish-college journalists are fine for this duty.

But also make sure you have at least one tech (coding) guy to make necessary things, like sitemaps, domains and markup... and one web designer (I mean, one person who understand about design, elements composition, colors, fonts, visual hierarchy, but also dominates HTML/CSS/Javascript techniques necessary to make web pages, not just fullfill your pages with tons of images).

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen a comprehensive guide on this, but if they are just writing and not implementing I would focus on 3 main areas:

Keyword research - by showing them how people search and what people search for, your writers will be able to write using the same language your searchers are using.

Principles of Writing - Understanding how writing formats can impact readers, explain using headings and subheadings, bulleted lists etc. (these all have markup that can be added by whoever implements but understanding the importance of laying out your article can be a big help).

Content types - you get more value using different writing styles for different types of content. IE a blog post should be conversational, whereas a white paper should be technical etc.

Comment: Thanks Joshak. I would give you a vote up but I don't have any rep.

Comment: No worries just happy to help.